# Разбиение массива методом explode

Tags: php, массивы

Есть данные которые лежат в файле `file.conf`. Я считываю его в двумерный массив, потом методом `explode` получаю таким, какой он мне нужен. Но мне нужно вернуть его в том исправленном виде, что у меня не получается. Сам код:

```
$array = file('Config.conf');
function explodearray()
{
    for ($i = 0; $i <= count($k); $i++) {
        for ($s = 0; $s <= count($k); $s++) {
            $k[$i][$s] = explode('%',$k[$i][$s]);
            echo $k[2][2];
        }
    }
    return $k;
    echo "done";
}
explodearray($array);`
```

Кусок `file.conf`:

```
Plate_1%59
DI_1%true%Switch 1%false%DO_1%2
DI_2%true%switch 2%true%DO_2%2`
```

На выходе я должен получить изменённый массив. Будьте добры, подскажите что-то.

Comment: Объясните что за "тот исправленный вид", в который вы хотите его(массив?) вернуть

Comment: Здравствуйте! А никак нельзя использовать *стандартный* формат, например JSON, вместо этого самопального ужаса? Тогда и чтение, и запись будут осуществляться  буквально одной строчкой.

Comment: Исправленный вид - это строка разбитая методом explode('%', $line);

Comment: В том то и дело, что json пока никак. Это файл конфигурации который я должен считывать и заносить в него информацию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может быть Вам подойдет вот этот код:

```
<?php

/**
 * Функция для "разбивания" строк
 * @param array $result
 */
function explodearray(array $arr) {

    $result = array();
    $result2 = array();
    $result3 = array();
    foreach ($arr as $string) {
        //Можно так (Вар 1)
        $result[] = explode("%", $string);

        //Или так (Вар 2)
        $parameters = array_chunk(explode("%", $string), 2);
        foreach ($parameters as $one) {
            if (isset($one[0]) AND isset($one[1])) {
                $result2[$one[0]] = $one[1];
            }
        }

        //Или так (Вар 3)
        $result3 = array_merge($result3, explode("%", $string));

    }
    echo "Вариант 1: ";
    print_r($result);
    echo "Вариант 2: ";
    print_r($result2);
    echo "Вариант 3: ";
    print_r($result3);

    return $result;
}

/**
 * Функция file() получает содержимое файла в виде массива строк.
 * Возьмем Ваш тестовый пример содержимого и завернем его в массив
 */
$file_conf = array(
    "Plate_1%59",
    "DI_1%true%Switch 1%false%DO_1%2",
    "DI_2%true%switch 2%true%DO_2%2"
);

explodearray($file_conf);
```